# Error while taking saving screenshots taken after each scenario

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber

I got an error saying world.attach is not a function.
I'm using a custom world constructor as shown below:

```
const {setWorldConstructor, attach} = require('cucumber')

class CustomWorld{
  constructor(){
    console.log('initilize stuff here')
    this.attach = attach;
    //var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  }
 //Some more code 
setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld)
```

Here is my hooks.js file

```
var {After, Status} = require('cucumber'); 
After(function (testCase) {
  var world = this;
  if (testCase.result.status === Status.FAILED) {
    return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(screenShot) {
      // screenShot is a base-64 encoded PNG
      world.attach(screenShot, 'image/png');
    });
  }
  //taking screenshots anyway 
  else{
        return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(screenShot) {
      // screenShot is a base-64 encoded PNG
      world.attach(screenShot, 'image/png');
      });
  }
});
```

Since I'm a newbie to this I probably have not done much correctly.
Can anyone please help me with how to save screenshots and generate reports in cucumber ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/darrinholst/b44dd51efb9122ee1a63de22debb6279) GitHubGist entry?

Comment: @Jeroen Heier : which version of cucumber does this run on ? I'm using version 4.X